# Unable to set div.style.left and div.style.top css properties via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position

I ran in a very confusing problem today

I have a canvas, and a div, like this

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="xy"></div>
```

I then set the properties of the div via a css file, e.g. position:absolute and display:none
Then, i write the X/Y Position in the div via JS and try to set the properties of the div so that the div follows the mouse around, like this

```
var div = document.getElementById("xy");
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 1;
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop - y0 - 0.5;
div.style.display = "block";
div.style.left = e.pageX + 25;
div.style.top = e.pageY -10;
div.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
```

The funny thing now is: i can set the display and backgroundColor without a problem, but the left and top properties don't work. If i delete my DOCTYPE-declaration in my HTML file though, i can modify the left and top properties without any trouble. Working without doctype is out of the question of course.
Am i doing something that shouldn't be done or missing something completely obvious?

Comment: What's "e" in that code? *edit* oh that's an event handler.

Answer (score 14):

You have forgotten "px":

```
div.style.left = (e.pageX + 25) + 'px';
div.style.top = (e.pageY -10) + 'px';
```

You might also want to add `div.style.position = "absolute";`

If you think there's any chance that `e.pageX` or `e.pageY` will be strings rather than numbers, throw a `parseInt` in:

```
div.style.left = (parseInt(e.pageX, 10) + 25) + 'px';
div.style.top = (parseInt(e.pageY, 10) - 10) + 'px';
```

Comment: +1, but your `parseInt` is unnecessary or, if required, has the ending `)` in the wrong place. I believe `e.pageX` is already a number, but if there's any chance it isn't, you want `= (parseInt(e.pageX, 10) + 25) + 'px';` (Note I also put the radix on it. You almost always want to tell `parseInt` specifically what radix to use.)

Comment: yes, but as it is a concatenated string it's more secure.
I personally prefer :). (alright for the radix, I will use now :))

Comment: My point is that what's there is actively wrong, not that it's not ideal. **If** `e.pageX` is a string (say, `"10"`), then `parseInt(e.pageX + 25)` will be `1025`, not `35`, because when you add a number to a string, the number is converted to text and *appended*: http://jsbin.com/ekiwup

Comment: that was just it. my head just met my desk at a high velocity. thank you very much ;) what i already had tried was + ' px', but there mustn't be a ' ' in it, i realized just now

Comment: the parseInt isn't even necessary, it works with just (e.pageX + 25) + 'px'

Comment: @RamonWenger: Yeah, that's what I said up above. `pageX` and `pageY` are already numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Another method for setting style properties like DIV objects is using the setProperty method

You can check below Javascript code sample

```
document.getElementById('div').style.setProperty("top","100px");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem, but when I added a space into the empty div, it started positioning properly. i.e.

```
div.innerHTML = &nbsp;&nbsp;
```